# How can I solve a deadlock between transactions that are primarily inserting data?

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

We have a situation where two web applications are working on the same database. They are both using TransactionScope (in c#) to encapsulate an importing routine.

We are getting a deadlock from two statements inside each of the transactionscopes. The first one is:

```
DELETE FROM Period WHERE CompanyId = 72
```

and the second is:

```
insert bulk Amount ([AccountId] Int, [PeriodId] Int, [Value] Decimal(18,2)) with (CHECK_CONSTRAINTS)
```

It's the first statement that is getting killed. Can anyone suggest how to get around this deadlock?

A few other points of interest:

- The transaction scopes are IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted.
- The database is ReadCommitted.
- I've tried it with READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT but it didn't make a difference.
- You can see from the second statement that we are using sqlbulkcopy during the transaction.
- Most of the time these applications will be read-heavy, however every now and then they will get intense bursts of writing as they import new data. I am hoping ReadCommitted is the right Isolation level.
- I don't understand why an insert into the amount table requires an exclusive lock on the period clustered index/table. Surely it is just reading the index.

The database structure is:

**Company**

Id

**Period**

Id,CompanyId

**Account**

Id

**Amount**

PeriodId,AccountId,Value

There is a CASCADE DELETE in place between Company and Period, Period and Amount, Company and Account.

**Deadlock XML**

```
<deadlock-list>
 <deadlock victim="process7373048">
  <process-list>
   <process id="process7373048" taskpriority="0" logused="53608" waitresource="KEY: 5:72057594040811520 (55caf8cfebcf)" waittime="262" ownerId="21707350" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2011-11-11T14:26:47.660" XDES="0x72af950" lockMode="U" schedulerid="1" kpid="1212" status="suspended" spid="57" sbid="2" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2011-11-11T14:26:49.273" lastbatchcompleted="2011-11-11T14:26:49.273" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="Fathom-1" hostpid="3396" loginname="fathom_WebUser" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="21707350" currentdb="5" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" sqlhandle="0x02000000bbf5661cad04d2a71e72d51fe7835afad57a3259">
DELETE FROM Period WHERE CompanyId = 105 AND Type = 7 AND DateRangeId IN (
                    SELECT Id 
                    FROM DateRange
                    WHERE Start &gt;= &apos;20110101 00:00:00&apos;)     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
DELETE FROM Period WHERE CompanyId = 105 AND Type = 7 AND DateRangeId IN (
                    SELECT Id 
                    FROM DateRange
                    WHERE Start &gt;= &apos;20110101 00:00:00&apos;)    </inputbuf>
   </process>
   <process id="process2c37e508" taskpriority="0" logused="570716" waitresource="KEY: 5:72057594040352768 (a559124170e7)" waittime="1330" ownerId="21707151" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2011-11-11T14:26:46.640" XDES="0x7207950" lockMode="S" schedulerid="1" kpid="3068" status="suspended" spid="58" sbid="2" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2011-11-11T14:26:48.203" lastbatchcompleted="2011-11-11T14:26:48.203" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="Fathom-1" hostpid="3396" loginname="fathom_WebUser" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="21707151" currentdb="5" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" sqlhandle="0x020000001672aa048fceb23bce7f8c54178cbbe497dba1a6">
insert bulk Amount ([AccountId] Int, [PeriodId] Int, [Value] Decimal(18,2)) with (CHECK_CONSTRAINTS)     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
insert bulk Amount ([AccountId] Int, [PeriodId] Int, [Value] Decimal(18,2)) with (CHECK_CONSTRAINTS)    </inputbuf>
   </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
   <keylock hobtid="72057594040811520" dbid="5" objectname="fathom.dbo.Period" indexname="PK_Period" id="lock2ab24500" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594040811520">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process2c37e508" mode="X"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process7373048" mode="U" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </keylock>
   <keylock hobtid="72057594040352768" dbid="5" objectname="fathom.dbo.Account" indexname="PK_Account" id="lock1ce65980" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594040352768">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process7373048" mode="X"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process2c37e508" mode="S" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </keylock>
  </resource-list>
 </deadlock>
</deadlock-list>
```

[image: Deadlock Graph]

Execution Plan For the bulk in sert (right side)

```
<ShowPlanXML xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan" Version="1.1" Build="10.50.2500.0"><BatchSequence><Batch><Statements><StmtSimple><QueryPlan CachedPlanSize="40" CompileTime="4" CompileCPU="4" CompileMemory="288"><RelOp NodeId="1" PhysicalOp="Assert" LogicalOp="Assert" EstimateRows="8100" EstimateIO="0" EstimateCPU="0.005508" AvgRowSize="9" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="4.81146" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0"><OutputList/><Assert StartupExpression="0"><RelOp NodeId="2" PhysicalOp="Merge Join" LogicalOp="Left Semi Join" EstimateRows="8100" EstimateIO="0.025979" EstimateCPU="0.0311493" AvgRowSize="9" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="4.80595" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0"><OutputList><ColumnReference Column="Expr1012"/><ColumnReference Column="Expr1013"/></OutputList><Merge ManyToMany="1"><InnerSideJoinColumns><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Period]" Column="Id"/></InnerSideJoinColumns><OuterSideJoinColumns><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Amount]" Column="PeriodId"/></OuterSideJoinColumns><Residual><ScalarOperator ScalarString="[fathom].[dbo].[Amount].[PeriodId]=[fathom].[dbo].[Period].[Id]"><Compare CompareOp="EQ"><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Amount]" Column="PeriodId"/></Identifier></ScalarOperator><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Period]" Column="Id"/></Identifier></ScalarOperator></Compare></ScalarOperator></Residual><RelOp NodeId="3" PhysicalOp="Sort" LogicalOp="Sort" EstimateRows="9000" EstimateIO="0.0112613" EstimateCPU="0.465821" AvgRowSize="12" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="4.74537" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Amount]" Column="PeriodId"/><ColumnReference Column="Expr1012"/></OutputList><MemoryFractions Input="0.42446" Output="1"/><Sort Distinct="0"><OrderBy><OrderByColumn Ascending="1"><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Amount]" Column="PeriodId"/></OrderByColumn></OrderBy><RelOp NodeId="4" PhysicalOp="Merge Join" LogicalOp="Left Semi Join" EstimateRows="9000" EstimateIO="0.027857" EstimateCPU="0.0353131" AvgRowSize="12" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="4.26829" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Amount]" Column="PeriodId"/><ColumnReference Column="Expr1012"/></OutputList><Merge ManyToMany="1"><InnerSideJoinColumns><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Account]" Column="Id"/></InnerSideJoinColumns><OuterSideJoinColumns><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Amount]" Column="AccountId"/></OuterSideJoinColumns><Residual><ScalarOperator ScalarString="[fathom].[dbo].[Amount].[AccountId]=[fathom].[dbo].[Account].[Id]"><Compare CompareOp="EQ"><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Amount]" Column="AccountId"/></Identifier></ScalarOperator><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Account]" Column="Id"/></Identifier></ScalarOperator></Compare></ScalarOperator></Residual><RelOp NodeId="5" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Insert" LogicalOp="Insert" EstimateRows="10000" EstimateIO="0.201195" EstimateCPU="0.01" AvgRowSize="15" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="4.19121" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Amount]" Column="AccountId"/><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Amount]" Column="PeriodId"/></OutputList><Update DMLRequestSort="1"><Object Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Amount]" Index="[PK_Amount]" IndexKind="Clustered"/><SetPredicate><ScalarOperator ScalarString="[fathom].[dbo].[Amount].[AccountId] = RaiseIfNullInsert([!BulkInsert].[AccountId]),[fathom].[dbo].[Amount].[PeriodId] = RaiseIfNullInsert([!BulkInsert].[PeriodId]),[fathom].[dbo].[Amount].[Value] = RaiseIfNullInsert([Expr1005])"><ScalarExpressionList><ScalarOperator><MultipleAssign><Assign><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Amount]" Column="AccountId"/><ScalarOperator><Intrinsic FunctionName="RaiseIfNullInsert"><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Table="[!BulkInsert]" Column="AccountId"/></Identifier></ScalarOperator></Intrinsic></ScalarOperator></Assign><Assign><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Amount]" Column="PeriodId"/><ScalarOperator><Intrinsic FunctionName="RaiseIfNullInsert"><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Table="[!BulkInsert]" Column="PeriodId"/></Identifier></ScalarOperator></Intrinsic></ScalarOperator></Assign><Assign><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Amount]" Column="Value"/><ScalarOperator><Intrinsic FunctionName="RaiseIfNullInsert"><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Column="Expr1005"/></Identifier></ScalarOperator></Intrinsic></ScalarOperator></Assign></MultipleAssign></ScalarOperator></ScalarExpressionList></ScalarOperator></SetPredicate><RelOp NodeId="6" PhysicalOp="Sort" LogicalOp="Sort" EstimateRows="10000" EstimateIO="0.0112613" EstimateCPU="0.60342" AvgRowSize="24" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="3.98001" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0"><OutputList><ColumnReference Table="[!BulkInsert]" Column="AccountId"/><ColumnReference Table="[!BulkInsert]" Column="PeriodId"/><ColumnReference Column="Expr1005"/></OutputList><MemoryFractions Input="1" Output="0.57554"/><Sort Distinct="0"><OrderBy><OrderByColumn Ascending="1"><ColumnReference Table="[!BulkInsert]" Column="AccountId"/></OrderByColumn><OrderByColumn Ascending="1"><ColumnReference Table="[!BulkInsert]" Column="PeriodId"/></OrderByColumn></OrderBy><RelOp NodeId="7" PhysicalOp="Compute Scalar" LogicalOp="Compute Scalar" EstimateRows="10000" EstimateIO="0" EstimateCPU="0.001" AvgRowSize="24" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="3.36533" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0"><OutputList><ColumnReference Table="[!BulkInsert]" Column="AccountId"/><ColumnReference Table="[!BulkInsert]" Column="PeriodId"/><ColumnReference Column="Expr1005"/></OutputList><ComputeScalar><DefinedValues><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Column="Expr1005"/><ScalarOperator ScalarString="CONVERT_IMPLICIT(decimal(18,2),[!BulkInsert].[Value],0)"><Convert DataType="decimal" Precision="18" Scale="2" Style="0" Implicit="1"><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Table="[!BulkInsert]" Column="Value"/></Identifier></ScalarOperator></Convert></ScalarOperator></DefinedValue></DefinedValues><RelOp NodeId="8" PhysicalOp="Top" LogicalOp="Top" EstimateRows="10000" EstimateIO="0" EstimateCPU="0.001" AvgRowSize="24" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="3.36433" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0"><OutputList><ColumnReference Table="[!BulkInsert]" Column="AccountId"/><ColumnReference Table="[!BulkInsert]" Column="PeriodId"/><ColumnReference Table="[!BulkInsert]" Column="Value"/></OutputList><Top RowCount="1" IsPercent="0" WithTies="0"><TopExpression><ScalarOperator ScalarString="(0)"><Const ConstValue="(0)"/></ScalarOperator></TopExpression><RelOp NodeId="9" PhysicalOp="Remote Scan" LogicalOp="Remote Scan" EstimateRows="10000" EstimateIO="0" EstimateCPU="3.36333" AvgRowSize="24" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="3.36333" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0"><OutputList><ColumnReference Table="[!BulkInsert]" Column="AccountId"/><ColumnReference Table="[!BulkInsert]" Column="PeriodId"/><ColumnReference Table="[!BulkInsert]" Column="Value"/></OutputList><RemoteScan RemoteObject="STREAM"/></RelOp></Top></RelOp></ComputeScalar></RelOp></Sort></RelOp></Update></RelOp><RelOp NodeId="14" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" LogicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" EstimateRows="907" EstimateIO="0.0127546" EstimateCPU="0.0011547" AvgRowSize="11" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0139093" TableCardinality="907" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Account]" Column="Id"/></OutputList><IndexScan Ordered="1" ScanDirection="FORWARD" ForcedIndex="1" ForceSeek="0" ForceScan="0" NoExpandHint="0"><DefinedValues><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Account]" Column="Id"/></DefinedValue></DefinedValues><Object Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Account]" Index="[PK_Account]" IndexKind="Clustered"/></IndexScan></RelOp></Merge></RelOp></Sort></RelOp><RelOp NodeId="16" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" LogicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" EstimateRows="150" EstimateIO="0.003125" EstimateCPU="0.000322" AvgRowSize="11" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.003447" TableCardinality="150" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Period]" Column="Id"/></OutputList><IndexScan Ordered="1" ScanDirection="FORWARD" ForcedIndex="1" ForceSeek="0" ForceScan="0" NoExpandHint="0"><DefinedValues><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Period]" Column="Id"/></DefinedValue></DefinedValues><Object Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Period]" Index="[PK_Period]" IndexKind="Clustered"/></IndexScan></RelOp></Merge></RelOp><Predicate><ScalarOperator ScalarString="CASE WHEN [Expr1012] IS NULL THEN (0) ELSE CASE WHEN [Expr1013] IS NULL THEN (1) ELSE NULL END END"><IF><Condition><ScalarOperator><Logical Operation="IS NULL"><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Column="Expr1012"/></Identifier></ScalarOperator></Logical></ScalarOperator></Condition><Then><ScalarOperator><Const ConstValue="(0)"/></ScalarOperator></Then><Else><ScalarOperator><IF><Condition><ScalarOperator><Logical Operation="IS NULL"><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Column="Expr1013"/></Identifier></ScalarOperator></Logical></ScalarOperator></Condition><Then><ScalarOperator><Const ConstValue="(1)"/></ScalarOperator></Then><Else><ScalarOperator><Const ConstValue="NULL"/></ScalarOperator></Else></IF></ScalarOperator></Else></IF></ScalarOperator></Predicate></Assert></RelOp></QueryPlan></StmtSimple></Statements></Batch></BatchSequence></ShowPlanXML>
```

Execution plan for left side (delete)

```
<ShowPlanXML xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan" Version="1.1" Build="10.50.2500.0"><BatchSequence><Batch><Statements><StmtSimple><QueryPlan CachedPlanSize="104" CompileTime="9" CompileCPU="9" CompileMemory="544"><MissingIndexes><MissingIndexGroup Impact="34.2748"><MissingIndex Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Amount]"><ColumnGroup Usage="EQUALITY"><Column Name="[PeriodId]" ColumnId="2"/></ColumnGroup><ColumnGroup Usage="INCLUDE"><Column Name="[AccountId]" ColumnId="1"/></ColumnGroup></MissingIndex></MissingIndexGroup><MissingIndexGroup Impact="46.6451"><MissingIndex Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Result]"><ColumnGroup Usage="EQUALITY"><Column Name="[PeriodId]" ColumnId="2"/></ColumnGroup><ColumnGroup Usage="INCLUDE"><Column Name="[MetricId]" ColumnId="1"/></ColumnGroup></MissingIndex></MissingIndexGroup></MissingIndexes><RelOp NodeId="1" PhysicalOp="Sequence" LogicalOp="Sequence" EstimateRows="119.191" EstimateIO="0" EstimateCPU="0.000233964" AvgRowSize="9" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.49074" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0"><OutputList/><Sequence><RelOp NodeId="2" PhysicalOp="Table Spool" LogicalOp="Eager Spool" EstimateRows="1" EstimateIO="0" EstimateCPU="2.54684e-005" AvgRowSize="11" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.00431261" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Period]" Column="Id"/></OutputList><Spool><RelOp NodeId="3" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Delete" LogicalOp="Delete" EstimateRows="1" EstimateIO="0.01" EstimateCPU="1e-006" AvgRowSize="11" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.01685" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Period]" Column="Id"/></OutputList><Update DMLRequestSort="0"><Object Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Period]" Index="[PK_Period]" IndexKind="Clustered"/><RelOp NodeId="4" PhysicalOp="Top" LogicalOp="Top" EstimateRows="1" EstimateIO="0" EstimateCPU="1e-007" AvgRowSize="11" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.00684904" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Period]" Column="Id"/></OutputList><Top RowCount="1" IsPercent="0" WithTies="0"><TopExpression><ScalarOperator ScalarString="(0)"><Const ConstValue="(0)"/></ScalarOperator></TopExpression><RelOp NodeId="6" PhysicalOp="Nested Loops" LogicalOp="Inner Join" EstimateRows="1" EstimateIO="0" EstimateCPU="4.18e-006" AvgRowSize="11" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.00684894" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Period]" Column="Id"/></OutputList><NestedLoops Optimized="0"><OuterReferences><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Period]" Column="DateRangeId"/></OuterReferences><RelOp NodeId="7" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" LogicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" EstimateRows="1" EstimateIO="0.003125" EstimateCPU="0.0003121" AvgRowSize="20" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0034371" TableCardinality="141" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Period]" Column="Id"/><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Period]" Column="DateRangeId"/></OutputList><IndexScan Ordered="1" ForcedIndex="0" ForceScan="0" NoExpandHint="0"><DefinedValues><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Period]" Column="Id"/></DefinedValue><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Period]" Column="DateRangeId"/></DefinedValue></DefinedValues><Object Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Period]" Index="[PK_Period]" IndexKind="Clustered"/><Predicate><ScalarOperator ScalarString="[fathom].[dbo].[Period].[CompanyId]=(118) AND [fathom].[dbo].[Period].[Type]=(10)"><Logical Operation="AND"><ScalarOperator><Compare CompareOp="EQ"><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Period]" Column="CompanyId"/></Identifier></ScalarOperator><ScalarOperator><Const ConstValue="(118)"/></ScalarOperator></Compare></ScalarOperator><ScalarOperator><Compare CompareOp="EQ"><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Period]" Column="Type"/></Identifier></ScalarOperator><ScalarOperator><Const ConstValue="(10)"/></ScalarOperator></Compare></ScalarOperator></Logical></ScalarOperator></Predicate></IndexScan></RelOp><RelOp NodeId="8" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Seek" LogicalOp="Clustered Index Seek" EstimateRows="1" EstimateIO="0.003125" EstimateCPU="0.0001581" AvgRowSize="10" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0032831" TableCardinality="2554" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0"><OutputList/><IndexScan Ordered="1" ScanDirection="FORWARD" ForcedIndex="0" ForceSeek="0" ForceScan="0" NoExpandHint="0"><DefinedValues/><Object Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[DateRange]" Index="[PK_DateRange]" IndexKind="Clustered"/><SeekPredicates><SeekPredicateNew><SeekKeys><Prefix ScanType="EQ"><RangeColumns><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[DateRange]" Column="Id"/></RangeColumns><RangeExpressions><ScalarOperator ScalarString="[fathom].[dbo].[Period].[DateRangeId]"><Identifier><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Period]" Column="DateRangeId"/></Identifier></ScalarOperator></RangeExpressions></Prefix></SeekKeys></SeekPredicateNew></SeekPredicates><Predicate><ScalarOperator ScalarString="[fathom].[dbo].[DateRange].[Start]&gt;=&apos;2011-07-01&apos;"><Compare CompareOp="GE"><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[DateRange]" Column="Start"/></Identifier></ScalarOperator><ScalarOperator><Const ConstValue="&apos;2011-07-01&apos;"/></ScalarOperator></Compare></ScalarOperator></Predicate></IndexScan></RelOp></NestedLoops></RelOp></Top></RelOp></Update></RelOp></Spool></RelOp><RelOp NodeId="11" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Delete" LogicalOp="Delete" EstimateRows="107.939" EstimateIO="0.0116206" EstimateCPU="0.000107939" AvgRowSize="9" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.261311" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0"><OutputList/><Update DMLRequestSort="1"><Object Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Result]" Index="[PK_RatioResult]" IndexKind="Clustered"/><RelOp NodeId="13" PhysicalOp="Sort" LogicalOp="Sort" EstimateRows="107.939" EstimateIO="0.0112613" EstimateCPU="0.0012373" AvgRowSize="19" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.249583" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Period]" Column="Id"/><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Result]" Column="MetricId"/></OutputList><MemoryFractions Input="1" Output="1"/><Sort Distinct="0"><OrderBy><OrderByColumn Ascending="1"><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Result]" Column="MetricId"/></OrderByColumn><OrderByColumn Ascending="1"><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Period]" Column="Id"/></OrderByColumn></OrderBy><RelOp NodeId="14" PhysicalOp="Hash Match" LogicalOp="Inner Join" EstimateRows="107.939" EstimateIO="0" EstimateCPU="0.0863485" AvgRowSize="19" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.237084" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Period]" Column="Id"/><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Result]" Column="MetricId"/><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Result]" Column="PeriodId"/></OutputList><MemoryFractions Input="0" Output="0"/><Hash><DefinedValues/><HashKeysBuild><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Period]" Column="Id"/></HashKeysBuild><HashKeysProbe><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Result]" Column="PeriodId"/></HashKeysProbe><RelOp NodeId="15" PhysicalOp="Table Spool" LogicalOp="Eager Spool" EstimateRows="1" EstimateIO="0" EstimateCPU="2.54684e-005" AvgRowSize="11" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.00431261" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Period]" Column="Id"/></OutputList><Spool PrimaryNodeId="2"/></RelOp><RelOp NodeId="16" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" LogicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" EstimateRows="14974" EstimateIO="0.129792" EstimateCPU="0.0166284" AvgRowSize="15" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.14642" TableCardinality="14974" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Result]" Column="MetricId"/><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Result]" Column="PeriodId"/></OutputList><IndexScan Ordered="1" ForcedIndex="0" ForceScan="0" NoExpandHint="0"><DefinedValues><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Result]" Column="MetricId"/></DefinedValue><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Result]" Column="PeriodId"/></DefinedValue></DefinedValues><Object Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Result]" Index="[PK_RatioResult]" IndexKind="Clustered"/></IndexScan></RelOp></Hash></RelOp></Sort></RelOp></Update></RelOp><RelOp NodeId="21" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Delete" LogicalOp="Delete" EstimateRows="5.83333" EstimateIO="0.01" EstimateCPU="5.83333e-006" AvgRowSize="9" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0383844" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0"><OutputList/><Update DMLRequestSort="0"><Object Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[PeriodAlert]" Index="[PK_PeriodAlert]" IndexKind="Clustered"/><RelOp NodeId="22" PhysicalOp="Hash Match" LogicalOp="Inner Join" EstimateRows="5.83333" EstimateIO="0" EstimateCPU="0.0184047" AvgRowSize="15" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0283786" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[PeriodAlert]" Column="AlertId"/><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[PeriodAlert]" Column="PeriodId"/></OutputList><MemoryFractions Input="0" Output="0"/><Hash><DefinedValues/><HashKeysBuild><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Period]" Column="Id"/></HashKeysBuild><HashKeysProbe><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[PeriodAlert]" Column="PeriodId"/></HashKeysProbe><RelOp NodeId="23" PhysicalOp="Table Spool" LogicalOp="Eager Spool" EstimateRows="1" EstimateIO="0" EstimateCPU="2.54684e-005" AvgRowSize="11" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.00431261" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Period]" Column="Id"/></OutputList><Spool PrimaryNodeId="2"/></RelOp><RelOp NodeId="24" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" LogicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" EstimateRows="140" EstimateIO="0.00534722" EstimateCPU="0.000311" AvgRowSize="15" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.00565822" TableCardinality="140" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[PeriodAlert]" Column="AlertId"/><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[PeriodAlert]" Column="PeriodId"/></OutputList><IndexScan Ordered="1" ForcedIndex="0" ForceScan="0" NoExpandHint="0"><DefinedValues><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[PeriodAlert]" Column="AlertId"/></DefinedValue><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[PeriodAlert]" Column="PeriodId"/></DefinedValue></DefinedValues><Object Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[PeriodAlert]" Index="[PK_PeriodAlert]" IndexKind="Clustered"/></IndexScan></RelOp></Hash></RelOp></Update></RelOp><RelOp NodeId="26" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Delete" LogicalOp="Delete" EstimateRows="119.191" EstimateIO="0.01" EstimateCPU="0.000119191" AvgRowSize="9" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.186497" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0"><OutputList/><Update DMLRequestSort="0"><Object Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Amount]" Index="[PK_Amount]" IndexKind="Clustered"/><RelOp NodeId="27" PhysicalOp="Hash Match" LogicalOp="Inner Join" EstimateRows="119.191" EstimateIO="0" EstimateCPU="0.0947385" AvgRowSize="15" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.176378" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Amount]" Column="AccountId"/><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Amount]" Column="PeriodId"/></OutputList><MemoryFractions Input="0" Output="0"/><Hash><DefinedValues/><HashKeysBuild><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Period]" Column="Id"/></HashKeysBuild><HashKeysProbe><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Amount]" Column="PeriodId"/></HashKeysProbe><RelOp NodeId="28" PhysicalOp="Table Spool" LogicalOp="Eager Spool" EstimateRows="1" EstimateIO="0" EstimateCPU="2.54684e-005" AvgRowSize="11" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.00431261" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Period]" Column="Id"/></OutputList><Spool PrimaryNodeId="2"/></RelOp><RelOp NodeId="29" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" LogicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" EstimateRows="16806" EstimateIO="0.0586806" EstimateCPU="0.0186436" AvgRowSize="15" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0773242" TableCardinality="16806" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Amount]" Column="AccountId"/><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Amount]" Column="PeriodId"/></OutputList><IndexScan Ordered="1" ForcedIndex="0" ForceScan="0" NoExpandHint="0"><DefinedValues><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Amount]" Column="AccountId"/></DefinedValue><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Amount]" Column="PeriodId"/></DefinedValue></DefinedValues><Object Database="[fathom]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Amount]" Index="[PK_Amount]" IndexKind="Clustered"/></IndexScan></RelOp></Hash></RelOp></Update></RelOp></Sequence></RelOp></QueryPlan></StmtSimple></Statements></Batch></BatchSequence></ShowPlanXML>
```

Comment: Can you paste the actual XML from the deadlock graph into your question? (not just the image)

Comment: I've added the XML for the deadlock graph.

Comment: Can't see why those statements would acquire those locks either. Perhaps there are additional statements that were run earlier in the same transaction that actually acquired the locks? Also do you have any `ON DELETE` action set up on the FK between `Period` and `Amount`?

Comment: @dan - Can you run these queries `DECLARE @handle VARBINARY(64);
SET  @handle = 0x02000000bbf5661cad04d2a71e72d51fe7835afad57a3259 ;
SELECT [text] FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(@handle) t;
SELECT p.query_plan
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats s
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(s.plan_handle) p
WHERE s.sql_handle = @handle;` for every sqlhandle (`0x02000000bbf5661cad04d2a71e72d51fe7835afad57a3259` and `0x020000001672aa048fceb23bce7f8c54178cbbe497dba1a6`) from deadlock and post the results ?

Comment: I've added the cascade delete details

Comment: @Bogdan Sahlean - I'll give it a go - but I'm not sure exactly where I should be running this from. Management studio after the deadlock has occurred and resolved? or trigger it from inside the exception in c#?

Comment: @dan - That script can be executed from SSMS. The purpose is to see all statements (and to get a better image on how this DEADLOCK has happened) executed by both processes implied in this deadlock. Also, the second statement will show the cached plans. All those VARBINARY(64) values are taken from DEADLOCK XML (`<frame procname="adhoc" sqlhandle="0x...">`).

Comment: Ok - I run both applications and I see the deadlock in the profiler. One app throws an error and I stop the other one as soon as possible. I then switch to SSMS and run that script - but there are no results.

Comment: (1) In this case, if the plans are cached then it's very likely they have changed. So, you need to open the XML DEADLOCK file and search for new `sqlhandle` values (`<frame procname="adhoc" sqlhandle="0x...">`). (2) For some reason, the plans are not cached. In this case, you can intercept those queries (including BEGIN/COMMIT TRANSACTION) using SQL Profiler and then you can run this batch in SSMS (using Include actual execution plan option activated).

Comment: @Bogdan Sahlean - I tried using the most recent sqlhandle values but that didn't help. In terms of intercepting the queries in Profiler - there are hundreds of queries that are part of the transaction (which may be problem...) so it is not realistic for me to copy these from profiler to ssms. I have included the execution plans for the statements in question, if that helps. Are locks held on behalf of individual queries or does having the queries in a transaction mean that locks are held for longer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the main cause is the execution plan for the next statement:

```
DELETE FROM Period WHERE CompanyId = 105 AND Type = 7 AND DateRangeId IN (
                    SELECT Id 
                    FROM DateRange
                    WHERE Start >= '20110101 00:00:00')
```

The execution plan for this `DELETE` has at least two problematics `SCAN` operators (to see the graphical view of the XML execution plans I have used the free version of `SQL Sentry Plan Explorer` [(link)](http://www.sqlsentry.com/plan-explorer/sql-server-query-view.asp)):
[image]

I would create the next indices:

```
CREATE /*UNIQUE*/ INDEX IN_Result_PeriodId_MetricId
ON dbo.Result (PeriodId, MetricId);

CREATE /*UNIQUE*/ INDEX IN_Amount_PeriodId_AccountId
ON dbo.Amount(PeriodId, AccountId);

--Optional
CREATE /*UNIQUE*/ INDEX IN_PeriodAlert_PeriodId_AlertId
ON dbo.PeriodAlert(PeriodId, AlertId);
```

If these indices are UNIQUE please uncomment.

Comment: Thanks for the time you spent on this - it was very helpful and informative to boot.